# Changing value of some elements with xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

```
The input xml structure is like this:



  <Envelopes>
    <env:Envelope>
     <urn:MyFunction>
      <parameter1 attr1='df'>fdad</parameter1>
      <parameter2 attr2='ww'>dfsa</parameter2>
      <productData>
        <Id></Id>
        <Description></Description>
        <Price><Price>
      </productData>
    </urn:MyFunction>
    </env:Envelope>

    <env:Envelope>
     <urn:MyFunction1>
       <parameter1 attr1='df'>fdad</parameter1>
       <parameter2 attr2='ww'>dfsa</parameter2>
       <productData>
        <Id></Id>
        <Description></Description>
        <Price><Price>
       </productData>
    </urn:MyFunction>
   </env:Envelope>

   <env:Envelope>
     <urn:MyFunction1>
       <parameter1 attr1='df'>fdad</parameter1>
       <parameter2 attr2='ww'>dfsa</parameter2>
       <productData>
        <Id></Id>
        <Description></Description>
        <Price><Price>
       </productData>
    </urn:MyFunction>
   </env:Envelope>
 <Envelopes>
```

In my xsl I am doing the below:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <NewEnvelopes>
   <xsl:for-each select="//productData">
   <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
</xsl:copy>
</NewEnvelopes>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="productData/Description">
<Description>new Description</Description>
</xsl:template>
```

I intend to keep the rest of the `productData` elements and attributes same, but modify some of them. But the resulting xml gives the `description` element with the new value, but only the `text nodes` for the rest of the elements. How can I get all the rest of the nodes of productData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an identity template that will copy the input content. Try adding this to your XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```